# Saving graphs directly to chosen directory with plotly

Tags: plotly

In matplotlib  with the following command, it saves the graph to a chosen directory,without asking me if i want to download it, without poping out:

> plt.savefig("image.png")

That is want I exactly want to do with plotly.

One way that I found on plotly on how to save a plot is with:

> plotly.offline.iplot(fig, filename='plot_name' ,image="png")

But then It pops the download windows where I have to click to save it, and I cant have that because I have a lot of plots that have to be generated.

Comment: Could you please try in Chrome?, it auto downloads for me, I am using `Chrome 66.0.3359.181 (Official Build) (64-bit)`!